# Regex do not match if (.*) contains a string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, match, expression

I'm trying to match a string in a URL and all that comes after it **unless** what comes after it contains a certain string.

I tried:

```
(?:/path/)(.*)
```

Example strings:

```
//https://example.com/path/css/style (match)    
//https://example.com/path/css/style2 (match)
//https://example.com/path/css/notstyle (match)(but I'm looking for it to not)
```

Comment: does it always end either with 'style' or 'styleX' where X is a number?

Comment: No, That was just an example. I'm trying to get the path after "/path/" unless the section after (.*) contains "notstyle"

Comment: Tell us which regex engine/programming language, you are using, so we can make a regex that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match `/path/css/style` you might use

```
https?://\S*/path/css/style\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O0122T/1)

If you want to exclude `notstyle` you can use a negative lookahead after the matching the protocol:

```
https?://(?!\S*notstyle)\S*/path/\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7BqPY3/1)